# Express.js and multer: how to know when the files are all uploaded?

Tags: javascript, express, multer

I'm using Multer module for file uploads. While it all works ok, there's a warning at the end of their github page, which reads:
"WARNING: req.body is fully parsed after file uploads have finished. Accessing req.body prematurely may cause errors."

This has got me really worried. I just can't find a way to let the .post middleware know when the file(s) have been uploaded and req.body is ready to use. Here's my code:

app.js:

```
app.use(multer({ 
        dest: './uploads/',
        rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
            return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + Date.now();
        },
        putSingleFilesInArray: true       
        })
);
```

upload.js:

```
router.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res){
        res.render('uploads');
    })
    .post(function(req, res){
        //how to wait here for the file to upload?
    });
```

While I am aware of onParseEnd, but I don't know how to implement it, so that I have at least some kind of information about the upload process being finished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multer is part of the router chain. This means that express will execute multer first, and only once multer has completed parsing the form it will continue execution to your `.post()` handler. The warning on the page is meant for accessing `req.body` from multer callbacks, like `onFileUploadData()` and similar. Therefore, the order of execution is:

- onParseStart
- onFileUploadStart/onFileUploadData...
- onFileUploadComplete
- onParseEnd
- your `.post()` handler

Comment: Hey @MikiJ can i use request in onFileUploadComplete to move file to a different location?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the documentation correctly the warning is only applicable to the event handlers you can pass to multer itself. When the request reaches your handler multer is already done and all files are already uploaded.

The problem exists for example in the `rename` event which you already use, but this function actually receives four arguments `fieldname, filename, req, res`. That means you have access to the request before it is fully parsed.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2018, onFileUploadComplete(file, req, res) is no longer part of multer.

Comment: A little more detail here https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/360

Answer (score -1):

You can know it easily, there is option available in multer called

- onFileUploadComplete(file, req, res)

You can use this and send response from here.

https://github.com/expressjs/multer#options

```
    app.use(multer({
    dest: path.join(__dirname, '../uploads/fullsize'),
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        console.log(file.name + ' is starting ...');
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file, req, res) {
        console.log(file.name + ' uploading is ended ...');
        console.log("File name : "+ file.name +"\n"+ "FilePath: "+ file.path)
    },
    onError: function (error, next) {
        console.log("File uploading error: => "+error)
        next(error)
    }
    onFileSizeLimit: function (file) {
        console.log('Failed: ', file.originalname +" in path: "+file.path)
        fs.unlink(path.join(__dirname, '../tmpUploads/') + file.path) // delete the partially written file
    }

}));
```

Comment: Thats what i was asking: how do i know in my upload.js route (post) that files are uploaded before i start using body.parse? The code you have posted just writes in console that is done but how do i check that in upload.js file??? I have multer in app.js

Comment: How can I show the information of the fileupload start, complete, error in the html page ?