# Express.js / Multer. Response being sent before onFileUploadComplete is complete

Tags: javascript, express, multer

I am using the following stuff for a file upload service:

```
onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        uploadPath = "";
        imageDimensions = null;
        console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting to upload...');
    },
onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
        uploadPath = file.path;
        uploadPath = uploadPath.replace(/\\/g,"/");
        console.log("Upload complete. " + file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
        sizeOf(file.path, function (err, dimensions) {
            if (err){
                console.log("ERROR, Can't get size of image! " + err);
                return;
            }
            else{
                imageDimensions = { 
                    width : dimensions.width,
                    height: dimensions.height
                };
                console.log("Size of image: width: " + imageDimensions.width + ". height: " + imageDimensions.height);
            }

        });
    }
```

and

```
app.post('/imageupload',function(req,res){
  upload(req,res,function(err) {
    console.log("response is being send..");
    if(err) {
        return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    }
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.json({
        dimensions: imageDimensions,
        path: uploadPath
    });
});
```

});

From what I understand (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30458411/2742995) onFileUploadComplete is first processed before the .post handler is being executed. However, my console shows:

```
a.jpg is starting to upload...
Upload complete. file uploaded to uploadeddata\a1235412.jpg
response is being send..
Size of image: width: 2835, height: 1654
```

So it seems that right in the middle of the onFileUploadComplete function the .post handler is already being exectued..

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok yeah got it... the sizeOf function I used is async.....

```
var dimensions = sizeOf(file.path);
```

is the synced version.