# Multiple File Upload and rename by multer in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, multer

I intended to use multer to upload multiple file and then rename them back to their original names. The below are the sample code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var multer = require('multer');

app.use(express.static('public'));
var upload = multer({ dest: './upload/' });

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index.html");
})

app.post('/file_upload', upload.array('theFile', 2), function (req, res, next) {

    var errorcode = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
        fs.rename(req.files[i].path, req.files[i].destination + req.files[i].originalname, function (err) {
            errorcode = err;
        }(i));
    }

    if (errorcode != 0) {
        console.log("errorcode is " + errorcode);
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
    } else {
        res.json({
            message: 'File uploaded successfully',
        });
    }
})


var server = app.listen(8089, function () {

    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

I'm testing the above code on a windows server. And my observation is that the files can be uploaded successfully but the fs.rename() keeps returning error "1". And the renamed files in the targeted folder are always 1Kb. It seems that the rename function intends to fetch the files which might be still uploading. I'm not sure whether my understanding is correct. If so, is there a way to determine whether the files have been uploaded completely? Any suggestion for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use Multer's built-in renaming functionality?

Adapted from the documentation:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: '/path/to/uploads/folder',
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // Here we specify the file name to save it as
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
})

// And we can use it for example like this:
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `image` file 
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any 
})
```

However, there are a couple things you should be aware of if you take this approach:

- The client can send any type of file, with any (potentially incorrect) extension. This is a potential security risk.
- If two files are uploaded with the same name, the second file will overwrite the first.
- If you serve these files to other users, the security risk greatly increases. An attacker could create a script or HTML page and upload it, possibly giving it a different file name extension. There are several ways it could be run, such as if the user tries to open it in a new tab because an image didn't show up. The full implications of this, and how to deal with it, are a topic of their own.
- Finally, make very, very, sure that the user cannot write to a directory other than the uploads folder. What happens when `file.originalname` is something like `../../index.js`? It may be better to convert the file name to a slug.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried Multer's built-in functionality and it did work as expected. BTW, do you know whether there is a way to check a file have been completed downloaded in multer?

Comment: @Liang When it reaches your `app.post` route, it has completed. See https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/360#issuecomment-231001064 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/30458411/3714913

Comment: Thanks again. It sounds very clear from the above two posts. However, I'm still suspecting it. As aconfee metioned, "Interestingly, the file didn't seem to be available at that point which you expanded on."

Comment: @Liang Well, I don't know about that. Do you have any reason *other* than someone else's "didn't work" to suspect it? Any number of things could have been wrong in that case, and we can't look into it. Not saying it's not a problem with multer, just that it doesn't have to be.

Comment: It suspected that the files have not been fully uploaded when I attempted to change the filename. I'm not very sure about this. Anyway, now I adopt your proposed solution and thanks again.

Comment: @Liang I think by that time the file is already saved and it is too late to change the name. Since multer allows us to specify a function for naming files, it's given full control over the name at that point and most likely doesn't support changes after that (because it's too late). That's just a guess though.